# Parse a copy of the SYSVOL

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sysvol

I have a full copy of a client's SYSVOL folder. The only DC on site had failed and been restored, but that got me wondering if there was a tool to look through a copy of the SYSVOL folder for information about what was being applied by Group Policy. I know I could manually look through for a lot of the info, but this particular client had quite a few GPOs. Has anyone ever heard of or seen such a tool? Maybe a different way of accomplishing the same task?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. We spent some time looking into this last year and ended up semi manually documenting it all in a (giant) Excel sheet. There's a niche there though I reckon - if you come up with your own let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

AGPM will work just fine if you have Software Assurance and desktop optimization pack. If not, you can use some Powershell scripts to document your GPOs. [`Get-GPOReport`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461057.aspx) would probably do what you're looking for.

Comment: I looked at Get-GPOReport, and that will work well for an existing domain, but it doesn't look like I can just hand it an old copy of all the folders and files in the SYSVOL. I have software assurance, so I may check out AGPM later. Thanks!